# Print_r() and at sign (@)

Tags: php

how can I access property with at sign (@) - @order, in this case? 
Here is the output of print_r function:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [@order] => 0
        [name] => Arthotel Munich
        [address1] => Paul-Heyse-Strasse 10
        [city] => Munich
        [postalCode] => 80336
        [countryCode] => DE
        [airportCode] => MUC

    )
```

I have tried $object->@order, $object[@order], $object::order. None of them worked.

Comment: how did you set this variable?

Comment: @genesis: [It's not so hard.](http://www.ideone.com/USFo0)

Comment: It's output of print_r run with json_decoded string as input

Comment: use `json_decode($str, TRUE)`, which gives you an array instead an object, then you can use `$arr['@order']` without any trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can do

```
echo $object->{'@order'};
```

or with a [variable variable](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
$name = '@foo';
echo $object->$name;
```

But like Tomalak pointed out, you want to change that property name. It leads to fubar code.

Comment: Yes, avoid it because using this is _undefined_.

Comment: He's now going to accept this and use it in production code, because it's easier to _ignore_ the warning that this is completely undefined. How irresponsible. :(

Answer (score 4):

The rules for object properties are like the rules for any other variable name.

Thus, a property named `@order` is not legal. Call it something else that doesn't have crazy symbols in.

<sup>It is possible to get into this situation by converting an array to an object through casting.</sup>

Comment: Yes, but is is stdClass, as you can see.

Comment: @FlexJack: Yes, an object of type `stdClass`. Run `json_decode($str, true)` instead to get an array.